# plotting k-modes cluster in python

Tags: python, jupyter

I've got 10 clusters in k-modes,

data:- categorical(i converted to binary then run model).

used technology:- jupyter-python.

doubt:- 1. find accuracy.

2. plotting/visualising cluster in 2d and 3d.

Comment: What have you tried? Without any code snippet or data, it's hard to surmise what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be a good start.

```
#recreate data to feed into the algorithm
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(df['field1']),np.asarray(df['field2'])]).T

So now running the following piece of code:

# computing K-Means with K = 5 (5 clusters)
centroids,_ = kmeans(data,5)
# assign each sample to a cluster
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)

# some plotting using numpy's logical indexing
plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'ob',
     data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'oy',
     data[idx==2,0],data[idx==2,1],'or',
     data[idx==3,0],data[idx==3,1],'og',
     data[idx==4,0],data[idx==4,1],'om')
plot(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],'sg',markersize=8)
show()
```

This is a great resource.

https://www.pythonforfinance.net/2018/02/08/stock-clusters-using-k-means-algorithm-in-python/